# iPhone jQuery actions with drag and drop

Tags: jquery, iphone, html

I'm trying to achieve the following. When a user drags an icon to a specific location in the html page and keeps it for about 3 seconds it must create automatically a new page (if there is no page) otherwise go to the next page (or previous page).

Is this achievable with jQuery? If yes, how must I realise it?

I've discovered and tried to following solutions:

Using Remy Sharp mousedrop plugin. In this plugin I can use the timerinterval to calculate if I'm in a specific area for an amount of time.

```
$(this).mousedown(function(interval))
{

}
```

But somehow I don't get this te work with the drag and drop functionality of jQuery UI. I have already developed some code with jQuery UI, but if it is useful? I really don't know.

```
    $("#pickUpDiv").draggable({
    start: function () {

    },
    drag: function() {
        var timeOutPointer = -1;
        var focusElm       = $("#focusCenter");
        var leftTopPos     = focusElm.position();
        var height         = focusElm.height();
        var width          = focusElm.width();
        var rightBottomPos = {
            right:  leftTopPos.left + width,
            bottom: leftTopPos.top + height
        };

        var pos = $(this).position();

        if ((pos.left > leftTopPos.left && pos.top > leftTopPos.top) && (pos.left < rightBottomPos.right && pos.top < rightBottomPos.bottom)) {
            $(document).mousehold(function(timerInterval) {
                if (timerInterval == 30) {
                    createNewPage();
                } else {

                }
            });
        }
    },
    stop: function() {

    }
});
```

This is my test setup:

```
<div id="focusCenter" style="height: 200px; width: 200px; border: 1px solid black;">

</div>

<div id="pickUpDiv" style="height: 100px; width: 100px; background-color: red;">
    &nbsp;
</div>
```

I hope that someone can help me with this or at least point me in the right direction... :) Thank you in advance already.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to tie in to `touchstart` `touchmove` and `touchend` events

Here's an article regarding mobile safari's treatment of mouse/touch events: http://blogs.adobe.com/adobeandjquery/2011/03/07/the-current-state-of-touch-events/

**EDIT:**

Decided to edit my comment into my answer:

I did something similar to this. What I did was as the mouse entered an object I added a class to the object and set a timeout to see if the object still had a class after n seconds. on mouseout remove the class and delete the timer. I'll see if I can find example code if the explanation isn't enough. Mine was for dragging and dropping "files" in a tree structure and expanding a folder after hover and wait.

Comment: Yes Ive already seen that but thats not what i meant :) i want something like when you drag around with an icon to a specific area on a website and you hold it there for lets say 3 seconds it must move to the previous page when it exist or create a new page :)

Comment: I did something similar to this.  What I did was as the mouse entered an object I added a class to the object and set a timeout to see if the object still had a class after n seconds. on mouseout remove the class and delete the timer. I'll see if I can find example code if the explanation isn't enough.  Mine was for dragging and dropping "files" in a tree structure and expanding a folder after hover and wait.

Comment: Awsome! That's a very good explanation already! That's the direction what I need, thank you :)

Comment: @Michiel Peeters: I've updated my answer to include the comment.  Do you want me to find the sample code?